# How to dynamically add html after all items with a certain class

Tags: jquery

I have a form that allows a user to dynamically add new text input fields on the fly.  All text input fields have class "dropBox".

How can I dynamically add some html text after every future input field added to the DOM?

This is what I have tried, but it is a silly work around.  There must be something better?

```
$(document).on("hover", function(){
    $(".dropBox:last").after("<i class='fa fa-chevron-down'></i>");
});
```

Comment: Couldn't/shouldn't this be done at the point at which you create/append the new `.dropBox` elements?

Comment: What method do the users "dynamically add" new text input fields? Are these created in Javascript?

Comment: yes, the html could be appended to the .dropbox items when it is generated - but some .dropbox items are hard coded in the DOM on load.  Id possible, I'd like to have one single line of code that handles both cases.